# ArgumentError: missing required option :key

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am trying to get an object from an S3 bucket via:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
    region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)

obj = s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object(args[:filename]).get # line causing error
```

The exact error message is:

> ArgumentError: missing required option :key

Answer (score 1):

The error message could be improved, but it means:

> ArgumentError: missing required **parameter** :key

("Parameters" and "arguments" are quite synonymous, and "options" sometimes get thrown into the mix, but a "required option" is confusing.)

I was refactoring some code and did not notice that `args[:filename]` was no longer being used... the `args` Hash was being used, but the `:filename` symbol was not, so it was returning `nil`:

```
> x = {}
 => {} 
> x.class
 => Hash 
> x[:blah]
 => nil
```

It worked once I updated the argument/parameter/option name (`args[:filename]`) to what was being used in the newly refactored source code.

By the way, [here's the line in the SDK that the error is coming from](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/d4a50ffae6054b3837ec929ad685375358713231/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3/object.rb#L1126).